# Unable to click on element though element is present in iOS

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I am automating an iOS application in browser stack. Though the element is visible, its unable to detect it to perform any click operation and script fails with the below error. Kindly help me in solving the issue.

failed - An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception Build info: version: '4.18.1', revision: 'b1d3319b48' System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '14.4', java.version: '17.0.10' Driver info: io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver Command: [7f47def139a42f3ef3fcdc54a46a3e9d060a8f6b, findElement {using=xpath, value=//XCUIElementTypeButton[@Label = ‘Close’}] Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, appium:autoAcceptAlerts: true, appium:autoGrantPermissions: true, appium:automationName: xcuitest, appium:bootstrapPath: /usr/local/.browserstack/co..., appium:browserstack.isTargetBased: true, appium:bundleID: com.zoll.respondcloud, appium:bundleId: com.zoll.respondcloud, appium:databaseEnabled: false, appium:deviceName: iPhone 11 Pro Max, appium:deviceOrientation: PORTRAIT, appium:javascriptEnabled: true, appium:keychainPassword: [REDACTED VALUE], appium:keychainPath: [REDACTED VALUE], appium:locationContextEnabled: false, appium:networkConnectionEnabled: false, appium:newCommandTimeout: 0, appium:noReset: true, appium:optimalHubUrl: hub-aps.browserstack.com, appium:orientation: PORTRAIT, appium:realMobile: true, appium:safariIgnoreFraudWarning: true, appium:safariInitialUrl: http://mobile-internet-chec..., appium:takesScreenshot: true, appium:udid: 00008030-0002381826D0802E, appium:useXctestrunFile: true, appium:waitForQuiescence: false, appium:wdaStartupRetries: 3, appium:webStorageEnabled: false, appium:webkitResponseTimeout: 20000, browserVersion: null, bstack:options: {buildIdentifier: #21, hostName: MAC-KCWGPMK09L}, platformName: IOS} Session ID: 7f47def139a42f3ef3fcdc54a46a3e9d060a8f6b

Comment: Hey! is this a react native application you are working with?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the Appium Inspector to take the locater on the app and try running the tests.

Ref: https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/integrations/appium-desktop

If you still face the issue, I would suggest you raise it with the BrowserStack support team.